# How to Vertically "center" align the multi line text

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Sorry if the title a bit misleading, I have difficulty to entitle it. It's also not exactly "center". (see below for further explanations)

Hi, I am going to make a project to write numbered musical scores. But I found an obstacle on leveling the "font". (See below picture for visual)

[image]

1. I need `1 2 3 3 1 2 3 4 4` to be in a straight "line"
2. I use `WrapPanel` as the container of my notes (as in the screen).

The main problem is on the pitch dot, which located **EITHER** above or below the note. Pitch is bound to the note, so I need process it in 1 User Control. But, if so, then I can't control the placement of the note "font" to be in one line.

Below is my note user control code :

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="RevisiConverter.NumericNoteBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=txbNote}" 
         Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=mainStack}">
<StackPanel Name="mainStack">
    <StackPanel Name="topStack">

    </StackPanel>
    <Canvas Name="canvas" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=txbNote}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=txbNote}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">            
        <TextBlock Name="txbNote" Text="1" Foreground="Black" FontSize="15"
                   Margin="0,0,0,-3" FontFamily="Courier" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0"/>
    </Canvas>
    <StackPanel Name="botStack">

    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
public partial class NumericNoteBox : UserControl
{
    private Note _child;
    private Line _sharp;

    public Note Child
    {
        get { return _child; }
        set
        {
            _child = value;
            Update();
        }
    }

    public NumericNoteBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _sharp = null;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        txbNote.Text = _child.MainNote.ToString();

        if (_sharp != null)
        {
            _sharp.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        topStack.Children.Clear();
        botStack.Children.Clear();

        if (_child != null)
        {
            if (_child.Pitch > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _child.Pitch; i++)
                {
                    topStack.Children.Add(new Ellipse());
                    (topStack.Children[topStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Width = 3;
                    (topStack.Children[topStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Height = 3;
                    (topStack.Children[topStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Fill = Brushes.Black;

                    if (_child.Accidental != Note.Accidentals.Flat)
                    {
                        (topStack.Children[topStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Margin = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (topStack.Children[topStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Margin = new Thickness(8, 1, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (_child.Pitch < 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Math.Abs(_child.Pitch); i++)
                {
                    botStack.Children.Add(new Ellipse());
                    (botStack.Children[botStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Width = 3;
                    (botStack.Children[botStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Height = 3;
                    (botStack.Children[botStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Fill = Brushes.Black;

                    if (_child.Accidental != Note.Accidentals.Flat)
                    {
                        (botStack.Children[botStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Margin = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (botStack.Children[botStack.Children.Count - 1] as Ellipse).Margin = new Thickness(8, 1, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (_child.Accidental == Note.Accidentals.Flat)
            {
                txbNote.Text = "b" + _child.MainNote.ToString();
            }
            else if (_child.Accidental == Note.Accidentals.Sharp)
            {
                if (_sharp == null)
                {
                    _sharp = new Line();
                    _sharp.X1 = 10;
                    _sharp.Y1 = 2.5;
                    _sharp.X2 = -2.5;
                    _sharp.Y2 = 12.5;
                    _sharp.StrokeThickness = 1;
                    _sharp.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

                    canvas.Children.Add(_sharp);
                }

                _sharp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note :

1. I'm not bound to that code, so if any of you have dealt to things like this more efficiently with totally different approach, then it's always welcome.
2. Sorry for some grammar error, if any, since english is not my first language.
3. I feel that I have not explained my problem real clear, since I also quite confused on it, so, please clarify anything you need.

Thanks

ADDITIONAL DETAILS :

1. The dot theoretically **doesn't have certain limitation**, but in practice, it's usually only 3 maximum (either 3 on top or 3 on bottom - not both)
2. In my code above, the note user control is divided into 3 grid row, the top one is for stacking the top dot, the mid one is for visualizing the note (numbers) and the bot one is for stacking the bot dot.
3. Please clarify anything, and I'll add more.

Comment: What's the maximum number of dots above and below the number, and how exactly do they have to be placed? This should all be done by a proper ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for clarifying. I have made some additional details on the bottom of the OP, please check it out. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this with an ItemsControl which use an appropriate `ItemTemplate` for the numeric notes.

First, create a ViewModel that defines a collection of "numeric note" items:

```
public class NumericNoteItem
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Pitch { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        NumericNotes = new ObservableCollection<NumericNoteItem>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<NumericNoteItem> NumericNotes { get; private set; }
}
```

In the constructor of your MainWindow, you may set the DataContext to an instance of this ViewModel like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.NumericNotes.Add(new NumericNoteItem { Number = 1, Pitch = 0 });
    vm.NumericNotes.Add(new NumericNoteItem { Number = 2, Pitch = 1 });
    vm.NumericNotes.Add(new NumericNoteItem { Number = 3, Pitch = -1 });
    vm.NumericNotes.Add(new NumericNoteItem { Number = 4, Pitch = 0 });
    vm.NumericNotes.Add(new NumericNoteItem { Number = 5, Pitch = 2 });
    vm.NumericNotes.Add(new NumericNoteItem { Number = 6, Pitch = -2 });
    vm.NumericNotes.Add(new NumericNoteItem { Number = 4, Pitch = 0 });
    vm.NumericNotes.Add(new NumericNoteItem { Number = 5, Pitch = 3 });
    vm.NumericNotes.Add(new NumericNoteItem { Number = 6, Pitch = -3 });

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

For visualizing the pitch I'd recommend to use a `Path` object with a Geometry that consists of a number of EllipseGeometries. To achieve this you would implement a binding converter that converts the pitch number into a Geometry, like shown below. It uses the `parameter` argument of the Convert method to create a Geometry for either positive or negative pitch values.

```
public class NotePitchConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const double radius = 1.5;
    private const double distance = 2 * radius + 1;

    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var pitch = (int)value;
        var geometry = new GeometryGroup();

        if (parameter as string == "Bottom")
        {
            pitch = -pitch;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pitch; i++)
        {
            geometry.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(
                new Point(radius, radius + i * distance), radius, radius));
        }

        return geometry;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Now, in XAML you would create an instance of this converter in e.g. the MainWindow `Resources`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NotePitchConverter x:Key="NotePitchConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and write the ItemsControl like shown below. Note that the DataTemplate uses a fixed height for the Path elements that show the top and bottom pitch. If you need to show more than three dots, you'd need to increase their height.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NumericNotes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Path Grid.Row="0" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                      Data="{Binding Pitch,
                             Converter={StaticResource NotePitchConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                <Path Grid.Row="2" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Data="{Binding Pitch,
                             Converter={StaticResource NotePitchConverter},
                             ConverterParameter=Bottom}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I need to study your code a bit more, since there are a lot of new things for me. But for simplification sake, your point is to make a fixed-height panel (in this case, `Cell`) first for the dot(s), right?? (So the height will stays equal)

Comment: Exactly that, plus that you should not manipulate UI elements in code, but instead make yourself familiar with MVVM.

Comment: I know this is off topic, but isn't XAML.CS is also a ViewModel? Still can't catch that. And what do you mean by manipulate UI Elements in code? So I can't, for example, add a StackPanel to a Grid Cell?

Comment: Actually not. In a real MVVM WPF application you would neither create UI elements in code (like `new Ellipse()`) nor would you add them to container controls (like `topStack.Children.Add(...)`). Instead, all this dynamic stuff would have a representation in a view model and would be visualized by data templates (e.g. in an ItemsControl).

Comment: for what purpose? is it to prevent 1 child "owned" by 2 parents?

Comment: That's software architecture. Here, it's for separating the view from the logic. You may search the web for `MVVM`. There are plenty of resources to start reading.